# How to remove clouds with the cf_mask.tif file provided from landsat 8 surface reflectance data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ndvi, landsat-8, cloud-cover

I just downloaded my first group of landsat 8 surface reflectance data files. In this package contains sr bands 1-7 (I hope to use some of these to create an NDVI) as well as numerous files called: sr_cloud, cf_mask, and cf_mask_conf (all tif files). I am using arcgis.

I am assuming that these files are utilised to help remove cloud coverage from the images. However, I have never dealt with any of these types of files (srcloud, cfmask, etc.) and I have no idea regarding how they work or how to use them to effectively remove clouds. Does anyone have any experience working with these kinds of files and know how I may effectively use to remove clouds?

Answer (score 3):

The cf_mask file identifies cloud (Pixel value 4), cloud shadow (2), snow (3), and water (1) pixels. Assuming you only want "clear land" pixels (0) you can use the **Con** tool with the following options

```
Input Conditional raster = "cfmask.tif"
Expression = "Value = 0"
Input true raster = "<surface reflectance layer>"
```

Use the composite bands tool to make a multi-band raster which can be used instead of an individual layer for RGB plotting.

The sr_cloud layer provides information about the atmospheric correction needed on the scene.

You mention you want to use the surface reflectance layers to generate NDVI, this can be done pre-delivery by the USGS if you use the ESPA interface, https://espa.cr.usgs.gov.