# Is it possible to create an average image of the analyzed period after the removal of the clouds to fill the flaws in the images?

Tags: ndvi, google-earth-engine, masking, cloud-cover

```js
// study area
var local = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-42.2974, -20.5299,-40.9406, -19.1815]);
Map.addLayer(local);

var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')

// Fmask classification values var FMASK_CLEAR_GROUND = 0; var FMASK_WATER = 2; var FMASK_CLOUD_SHADOW = 3; var FMASK_SNOW = 4; var FMASK_CLOUD = 5;

var mosaic = landsat8 .filterBounds(local) .filterDate('2017-08-01', '2017-10-11') .mosaic();

var getQABits = function(image, start, end, newName) {
    // Compute the bits we need to extract.
    var pattern = 0;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
       pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    // Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the band
    // a new name.
    return image.select([0], [newName])
                  .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
                  .rightShift(start);
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var cloud_shadows = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['pixel_qa']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 3,3, 'Cloud_shadows').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var clouds = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['pixel_qa']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 5,5, 'Cloud').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

var maskClouds = function(image) {
  var cs = cloud_shadows(image);
  var c = clouds(image);
  image = image.updateMask(cs);
  return image.updateMask(c);
};

var mosaic_free = maskClouds(mosaic);

var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],min: [0,0,0],max: [2000, 2000, 2000]};

Map.addLayer(mosaic, visParams, 'With clouds'); 
Map.addLayer(mosaic_free, visParams, 'Cloud free'); 

// Average image

var median = ee.Image(mosaic_free.median())

Map.addLayer(median,
 {min:0, max: 3000, bands: 'B3, B2, B1'},
 'median composite of cloud free images');

// NDVI

var red = median.select('B4');
var nir = median.select('B5');


var calculo = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red));

//pallates NDVI 

  var ndvi_palette = 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D, F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400,'+
  '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01,012E01, 011D01, 011301';

var ndvi = calculo.clip(area);

Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min:-0.1, max: 1.0, palette: ndvi_palette}, 'NDVI');

// Visualization ------------------------------------------------------------------
Map.centerObject(area, 8);
```

After building a [cloud mask](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271322/cloud-mask-in-surface-reflectance-landsat-8-test/271878?noredirect=1#comment433029_271878), is it possible to create an average image of the period without the presence of faults to calculate the NDVI? I have adapted the link code for my study area, but I am not able to create a averege image without the presence of clouds to calculate the NDVI.

Comment: It should work. Yet, not all that can be done, should be done. E.g., mixing up pictures from different points in time and platforms in order to create a time sensitive spectral analysis.

Comment: This question is much too vague. The short answer is: Yes, it is possible. If you want help, detail what you have already attempted and where exactly you are stuck.