# Landsat 8 extracted pixel values for up North: 'pixel_qa' value of 322

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, landsat-8, cloud-cover, data-quality

I am trying to get landsat reflectance values corresponding to field plots spread all over Finland using the Google Earth Engine. As you know, Finland is up North, between latitudes of ~60 and 70 degree N. I am extracting from [this landsat collection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_SR). Upon examining the extracted values, I noticed that most (99.9%) of the pixels have a 'pixel_qa' value of 322. From my understanding of the bitmask, I gathered that the value of '322' means that the 'cloud confidence' and the 'cirrus confidence' was low. Why is this? Can I still assume that the cloud/noncloud classification is good enough?

Answer (score 1):

I got a reply from someone at USGS: "You want low confidence in clouds, that means that there is very little chance that there is a cloud there when there shouldn't be.
A value of 322 means that the pixels are clear and there are not clouds present."

So, in conclusion, a value of 322 is okay to work with.

Comment: Is more than that, you should decode `pixel_qa` band in the bits you need. Check this question, it could help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271322/cloud-mask-in-surface-reflectance-landsat-8-test/271329#271329

Comment: Thanks for that link! Actually, I was confused by what they meant in bits 6-7 and 8-9. For example, a "cloud confidence" value of "none" seems to say that the algorithm has very low confidence on its output (clouds vs no-cloud)! I have given the feedback to the USGS person that they may want to word that better. Something like "probability of cloud contamination in the pixel"...

Comment: As far I know, `none` is non-determine status. Check this page: https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/nli/landsat/landsat-collection-1-level-1-quality-assessment-band?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con