# The QA band of some Landsat 8 images seems to be invalid

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap, cloudmasking

I am quite confused about some invalid qa masks.
In some images, the VALUE of the QA band is shown as 21824 (cloudless)[image: invalid QA value], but the location is actually covered by cloud. In addition to Landsat images, the same is true of Sentinel2a images.

The mask method I used is as follows(on geemap in python language):

```py
    def L8cfmask (image) :
        qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(ee.Number.parse ('11111',2)).eq(0)
        SaturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0)
        rt = image.updateMask(qaMask).updateMask(saturationMask)

        return rt
```

Also, a GEE example is as followed:
[https://code.earthengine.google.com/e409034b609ea806eff892945b080e9a]

In this example, I copied the code from the official website[https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_composite_mosaic] and changed the center of the map to focus on the colud pixels with cloudless QA value.

The Bitmask for QA_PIXEL is here:

[https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2#bands]
[image: Bitmask for QA_PIXEL]

Is there any way to remove these incorrect images in QA band?

Comment: The code you posted is unreadable, so I can't help you as I want. But take a look at this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/271329/80215 . Check the metadata of QA_Pixel band and decode bites to check if 21824 is actually cloudless

Comment: @aldo-tapia I have added some links to my question. I think the bites I decode are correct...so confused...