# Parsing MOD13Q1 QA layer using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, modis

Working with Modis [MOD13Q1](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MOD13Q1) data and I am not sure how to correctly parse for pixel QA and DetailedQA.

```
// Call data 
var CRNP_Oban = ee.FeatureCollection("users/sijehasuk/CRNP_Oban2"),
    ndvi = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13Q1");

// Explore the variable to view QA
print(ndvi);

// Create function with filter of quality pixels
var mask = function(im) {
  return im.updateMask(im.select("SummaryQA").eq(0));
};
```

Version VI SummaryQ includes bits 0-1 from the DetailedQA and I have masked Bit '0' (please, correct if done wrongly)
****Note: Bitmask for SummaryQA

```
/// Bits 0-1: VI quality (MODLAND QA Bits)
// 0: Good data, use with confidence
// 1: Marginal data, useful but look at detailed QA for more information
// 2: Pixel covered with snow/ice
// 3: Pixel is cloudy

// Apply filter to NDVI data
var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection(ndvi)
.filterDate('2000-01-01','2020-01-01')
.map(mask)
.select("NDVI")
.filterBounds(CRNP_Oban);
```

How do I include Bitmask 1 and apply other Bitmask for DetailedQA (see below) to ensure the best quality of pixel? See help2 [Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/sijehasuk/stackexchange) and [asset](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/sijehasuk/CRNP_Oban2). While working on this in R, it was observed that the area had a lot of missing data issues. So it would be good to ease the QA a little so there is still some data left for analysis.

```
// VI quality indicators

// Bitmask for DetailedQA

// Bits 0-1: VI quality (MODLAND QA Bits)
// 0: VI produced with good quality
// 1: VI produced, but check other QA
// 2: Pixel produced, but most probably cloudy
// 3: Pixel not produced due to other reasons than clouds

// Bits 2-5: VI usefulness
// 0: Highest quality
// 1: Lower quality
// 2: Decreasing quality
// 4: Decreasing quality
// 8: Decreasing quality
// 9: Decreasing quality
// 10: Decreasing quality
// 12: Lowest quality
// 13: Quality so low that it is not useful
// 14: L1B data faulty
// 15: Not useful for any other reason/not processed

// Bits 6-7: Aerosol Quantity
// 0: Climatology
// 1: Low
// 2: Intermediate
// 3: High

// Bit 8: Adjacent cloud detected
// 0: No
// 1: Yes

// Bit 9: Atmosphere BRDF correction
// 0: No
// 1: Yes

// Bit 10: Mixed Clouds
// 0: No
// 1: Yes

// Bits 11-13: Land/water mask
// 0: Shallow ocean
// 1: Land (nothing else but land)
// 2: Ocean coastlines and lake shorelines
// 3: Shallow inland water
// 4: Ephemeral water
// 5: Deep inland water
// 6: Moderate or continental ocean
// 7: Deep ocean

// Bit 14: Possible snow/ice
// 0: No
// 1: Yes

// Bit 15: Possible shadow
// 0: No
// 1: Yes
```

See further description of the VI quality assessment.
[image: Further description of VI QA] [Source](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/documents/103/MOD13_User_Guide_V6.pdf)

Comment: Check this answer to decode QA bits: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271322/cloud-mask-in-surface-reflectance-landsat-8-test/271329#271329 I don't have enough time right now for writing an answer, but it'll be useful

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and any other statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure what values you wanted for each of the quality bits, so I wrote comments where you may want to adjust them.

```
var CRNP_Oban = ee.FeatureCollection("users/sijehasuk/CRNP_Oban2"),
    ndvi = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13Q1");
    ndvi = ndvi.map(function(image){ return image.clip(CRNP_Oban)});

// Create function with filter of quality pixels
var mask = function(im) {
  return im.updateMask(im.select("SummaryQA").eq(0));
};

ndvi = ndvi.map(mask);
// Explore the variable to view QA
print(ndvi);

// This function sets the starting position for the bit and the number of
// positions necessary.
var GetQABits = function(image, bitStart, numBits){
    var bitmapped = image.select('DetailedQA').rightShift(bitStart).mod(Math.pow(2, numBits));
    return bitmapped;
};

var MaskToBestBits = function(image){
  var detailqa = image.select('DetailedQA');
  var VIQual = GetQABits(detailqa, 0, 2);
  var VIUse = GetQABits(detailqa, 2, 4);
  var VIaer = GetQABits(detailqa, 6, 2);
  var Viadjcl = GetQABits(detailqa, 8, 1);
  var atmbrdf = GetQABits(detailqa, 9, 1);
  var mxdcl = GetQABits(detailqa,  10, 1);
  var lnwt = GetQABits(detailqa, 11, 3);
  var snowice = GetQABits(detailqa, 14, 1);
  var shadow = GetQABits(detailqa, 15, 1);
  // update the image mask to select the indicator values you.
  // the values in the following updateMasks are GUESSES based on what you posted
  // with regard to the indicator. For example, VI Quality has 2 values, 0
  // or 1, that are good, so used less than 2 ("lt(2)") to get either.
  return image.addBands(detailqa)
    .updateMask(VIQual.lt(2)) //Suggested, but not sure what you want here
    // .updateMask(VIUse.lt(8)) //Suggested, but not sure what you want here
    // .updateMask(VIaer.lt(3)) //Suggested, but not sure what you want here
    // .updateMask(Viadjcl.eq(1)) //Suggested, but not sure what you want here
    // .updateMask(atmbrdf.lt(1)) //Suggested, but not sure what you want here
    // .updateMask(mxdcl.eq(0)) //Suggested, but not sure what you want here
    // .updateMask(lnwt.eq(1)) //Suggested, but not sure what you want here
    // .updateMask(snowice.eq(0)) //Suggested, but not sure what you want here
    // .updateMask(shadow.eq(0)); //Suggested, but not sure what you want here
};

var newndvi = ee.ImageCollection(ndvi)
.filterDate('2000-01-01','2020-01-01')
.map(MaskToBestBits)
.select("NDVI")
.filterBounds(CRNP_Oban)
.map(function(im) { return im.clip(CRNP_Oban)});

print('newndvi', newndvi);


Map.addLayer(newndvi, null, 'newndvi');
Map.addLayer(ndvi, null, 'ndvi')
Map.setCenter(8.53, 5.56, 9);
Map.addLayer(CRNP_Oban, null, 'CRNP Oban')
```

Comment: I have updated my question with more information. As shown in the Modis document (image above), the detailedQA is in binary. Does that not apply when masking? Also, I guess I have to remove my initial mask
`var mask = function(im) {
  return im.updateMask(im.select("SummaryQA").eq(0));};` ?

Comment: I have removed the initial mask. The code works fine. Very much appreciated.

Comment: How can you select two undateMask values in between other values? For example, I have 0, 1, 2, 3 etc and I want to select 1 and 2 in the update mask section `.updateMask(Viadjcl.eq(1))`.

Comment: Your options are to use the logical operators, such as `eq` (equals), `lt` (less than), `lte` (less than or equal to), etc. I'm not 100% sure you can have one than one value. But since you want 1 and 2, and they're both less than 3, you can try `updateMask(VIQual.lt(3))`. The logic works. It's up to how the collection and GEE works on whether or not they allow more than one value. (I can't see a reason they can't). Worth a try. If that doesn't work, you should make a different post to ask if a mask (updateMask) of more than 1 value can be used with the QA bits for MOD13Q1 or something similar.

Comment: 0 is climatology, 1 is low, and 2 is intermediate but I'm not sure what climatology means. I've tried to read up on it but can't see anything substantial. I don't think it's worth asking another question. I'll just assume climatology is the best quality. Thank you.

Comment: I found this: https://www.ctahr.hawaii.edu/grem/mod13ug/sect0005.html If you go all the way to the bottom, there is a small paragraph about usefulness and I think you're right, you want the climatology rank. However, based on Table 5 in this doc: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/documents/103/MOD13_User_Guide_V6.pdf you wouldn't select climatology with VIQual, but with VIaer, so you may need to experiment with those bits.

Comment: @JohnPolo Great answer.  It looks like each call to updatemask() further narrows the set of pixels returned.  In the docs for the "mask()" function, it says: "To set a mask from an image on previously unmasked pixels, use Image.updateMask. To unmask previously masked pixels, use Image.unmask."  I wonder if the OP's goal was to broaden the set of pixels, rather than to narrow it, which might require a more complicated mix of AND/OR operations, i.e., mixing updatemask() and unmask() statements.

Comment: ...or Boolean AND/OR operations like `qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))`